# NBA game 4 home winners after trailing 0-3

Tags: trivia, basketball, nba, postseason

How many home teams have won game 4 after being down 0-3? A friend is saying it never happens. I disagree, it must happen sometimes.

Comment: By "never happens", does your friend actually mean "has never happened" or "happens very rarely"?

Comment: It should be easy enough to look up.

Comment: You might have a look at some of the games listed in the Wikipedia articles [Game seven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_seven#National_Basketball_Association) and [List of NBA game sevens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NBA_game_sevens).

Comment: And even just trying to Google might give you a few resources where you might find such series. For example, by searching for [nba comeback from 0-3](https://www.google.com/search?q=nba+comeback+from+0-3).

Comment: By home team you mean the team which plays game 4 at home? Would [1951 NBA Finals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1951_NBA_Finals) be an example of what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

> How many home teams have won game 4 after being down 0-3?

As of 2015, the home team with an 0-3 deficit won game 4 34 times.

---

This [2015 article](https://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/nba/playoffs/2015/05/26/james-harden-dwight-howard-rockets-warriors-kevin-mchale/27973993/) states:

> All 116 NBA teams that have faced a 3-0 deficit in a seven-game series have ultimately lost, with **34 forcing Game 5**, 10 forcing Game 6<sub>[(1)](http://www.nba.com/news/extendingseriestogame6.html)</sub> and three forcing Game 7<sub>[(1)](http://www.nba.com/news/extendingseriestogame6.html)</sub>.

---

Aside: As of the conclusion of the 2016 NBA Playoffs, the home team won game 4 in a best-of-seven playoff series 270 times<sub>[(2)](http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/tgl_finder.cgi?request=1&player=&match=game&lg_id=NBA&year_min=1947&year_max=2016&team_id=&opp_id=&is_range=Y&is_playoffs=Y&round_id=&best_of=7&team_seed=&opp_seed=&team_seed_cmp=eq&opp_seed_cmp=eq&game_num_type=series&game_num_min=4&game_num_max=4&game_month=&game_location=H&game_result=W&is_overtime=&c1stat=&c1comp=&c1val=&c2stat=&c2comp=&c2val=&c3stat=&c3comp=&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=&c4val=&order_by=date_game&order_by_asc=&offset=200)</sub>.